# I can't disable CORS in json-server

Tags: javascript, json-server

When I try to send data via POST to a json-server I get error 500, with Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin.

I tried using the `--no-cors` option to disable CORS (`npx json-server --watch db.json --port 3002 --no-cors`), but it didn't work. Then I tried to start a middleware using the `--Middleware server.js` option (`npx json-server --watch db.json --port 3002 --Middlewares server.js`), but that didn't work either.

How do I allow sending messages via POST to my json-server?

server.js:

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
jsonServer.defaults({ noCors: true })
```

handleSubmit:

```
async function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            const connection = await fetch("http://localhost:3002/messages", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: name,
                    messages: messages
                }),
            });
            const data = await connection.json();
            console.log(data);
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to **disable** CORS? It seems like you'll need it. Find the cause of the 500 error response instead. This would typically be reported in the terminal where you're running the server process

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the meaning of CORS. But in this case I need to enable CORS for localhost:3000 or any origin for my website to work.

Comment: The default for `json-server` is to allow all connections. Like I said already, determine the cause of the 500 error. This is **not** CORS related

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the JSON file was without an id and the POST was trying to send an id.

```
{
  "mensagens": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "nome": "Priscila da Silva",
      "mensagem": "Primeira mensagem de priscila"
    }
  ]
}
```